# MySQL multiple errors, columns not existing, tables not existing when called

Tags: mysql, sql

Learning MySQL, I'm trying to create a DB, create tables, insert info.

On creating the table with a foreign key I get the following:

> Error Code: 1072. Key column 'idFamous' doesn't exist in table    0.000 sec

On inserting data I get the following:

> Error Code: 1146. Table 'practice.people' doesn't exist   0.000 sec

I also get that same error if I attempt to `Select * From People`.

I'm familiar only with very basic python, so attempted to reorganize the order in which the tables/columns are created, so they exist before the other creates the foreign key. This didn't seem to have any effect.

```
CREATE TABLE Famous (
    idFamous INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FamousFor VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE People (
    idPeople int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    DOB DATE NOT NULL,
    Nationality VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (idFamous) REFERENCES Famous(idFamous) 
);

INSERT INTO Famous VALUES (01,'Computer Scientist');
INSERT INTO People VALUES (102,'Larry','Page',3/26/1973,'American',01);
```

Comment: You need the column `idfamous` to exist in the `People` table for that `FOREIGN KEY` instruction to work. So the `CREATE TABLE People` has failed

Comment: Your insert fails because the create table fails, the create table fails because People.idFamous does not exist (and must for it to reference Famous.idFamous).

Comment: Oh I see now, so its simply adding idFamous INT NOT NULL, as a field in People prior to the foreign key line?

The line(code?) that says FOREIGN KEY (idFamous)... doesn't create it within Mysql?

Just tried it, Thank you!
That perfectly answers my question, but I cant mark a comment here as the answer.

Comment: As `FOREIGN KEY` is a InnoDB only feature, i would suggest using a explicit `Engine = InnoDB` in the `CREATE TABLE` statement like `CREATE TABLE table_name (
    ...
) Engine = InnoDB ;` to make it not depend on default table storage engine configuration setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  declaration of table `People` is not valid SQL, and produces error:

> Key column 'idFamous' doesn't exist in table

To set up a foreign key, you first need to *declare* the column. That column must have the same datatype and size as the column being referred.

Change your table declaration to:

```
CREATE TABLE People (
    idPeople int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    DOB DATE NOT NULL,
    Nationality VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    idFamous INT NOT NULL,                             -- declare the referencing column
    FOREIGN KEY (idFamous) REFERENCES Famous(idFamous) -- then make a foreign key
);
```

---

NB: there is also an issue with your `INSERT` statement, where the `date` column needs to be quoted and formated like `yyyy-mm-dd`. This:

```
INSERT INTO People VALUES (102,'Larry','Page',3/26/1973,'American',01);
```

Will generate an error like:

> Incorrect date value: '0.000058481811961479' for column 'DOB'

Should be written as:

```
INSERT INTO People VALUES (102,'Larry','Page','1973-03-26','American',01);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iW7piqQddWPgC6T1FEaRPE/0)**.

---

Also, as commented by Raymond Nijland, as `FOREIGN KEY` is a InnoDB only feature, it could be a good idea to use a explicitly set `Engine = InnoDB` in the `CREATE TABLE` statement, so it does not depend on default table storage engine configuration setting. Hence:

```
CREATE TABLE People (
    ...
) Engine = InnoDB;
```

Comment: As `FOREIGN KEY` is a InnoDB only feature, i would suggest using a explicit `Engine = InnoDB` in the `CREATE TABLE` statement like `CREATE TABLE table_name (
    ...
) Engine = InnoDB ;` to make it not depend on default table storage engine configuration setting

Comment: @RaymondNijland: yes that's a good point. I updated my answer. Thanks!